# Disable double-tap scroll on WKWebView

Tags: swift, scroll, double-click, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I have a custom keyboard with a WKWebView in full width and height. I have disabled the scroll via `wkWebView!.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false` but I still have a strange scroll behavior at double-tap on the bottom of the WKWebView. Here the source-code of the simple webpage I try to load : http://is.gd/gt8h2q (very simple, just a div full screen with background green and one line of text). Below, a GIF as explanation. Here is how I create the WKWebView :

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {
var wkWebView: WKWebView?

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    let contentController = WKUserContentController()
    contentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name:"callbackTestOne")

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = contentController

    self.wkWebView = WKWebView(frame:self.view.frame, configuration:config)
    self.view = self.wkWebView!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    (...)

    wkWebView!.scrollView.bounces = false
    wkWebView!.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    wkWebView!.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:248, green:248, blue:248, alpha:1)
    wkWebView!.scrollView.opaque = true
    wkWebView!.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    wkWebView!.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    wkWebView!.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal
}

(...)
```

[image: GIF explanation]

Comment: Still unresolved problem... I found a dirty way to fix : in my local loaded page, I use jQuery to auto-scroll to top when scroll position is > 0. Code : `$(window).scroll(function() { if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 0 ) { $(window).scrollTop(0); }; });`

Comment: This is a real problem. The same thing happens when adding a WKWebView to an iMessage app or extension.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem and found a solution. That is, to remove the UITapGestureRecognizer that is responsible for the misbehavior.

The WKWebView, or more precisely the UIScrollView and it's subviews that are contained in the WKWebView, have a lot of gesture recognizers added. So you can easily iterate over all of those recognizers in the views and remove the one you need.

If you want to remove all 1-finger double-tap recognizers from the webView, you need to search inside the subviews of the scroll view. You could do the following:

```
// iterate over all subviews of the WKWebView's scrollView
for subview in _webView.scrollView.subviews {

    // iterate over recognizers of subview
    for recognizer in subview.gestureRecognizers ?? [] {

        // check the recognizer is  a UITapGestureRecognizer
        if recognizer.isKind(of: UITapGestureRecognizer.self) {

            // cast the UIGestureRecognizer as UITapGestureRecognizer
            let tapRecognizer = recognizer as! UITapGestureRecognizer

            // check if it is a 1-finger double-tap
            if tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired == 2 && tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired == 1 {

                // remove the recognizer
                subview.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Nice explanation! Work for my case - only allow one-tap. Thanks!

Comment: This way works for the web view initial rendering. But after you pinch to zoom the web page, the double tap gesture comes back. I haven't found the root cause.

Comment: it should be called after didFinish navigation, otherwise doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

Hacky and dirty solution. But at least it works. Just add your own UITapGestureRecognizer to a view contained WKWebView and make your UIViewController delegate to this gesture recognizer. I used this code:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    if ([[otherGestureRecognizer description] containsString:@"WKSyntheticClickTapGestureRecognizer"] && [[otherGestureRecognizer description] containsString:@"numberOfTapsRequired = 2"]) {
        [otherGestureRecognizer removeTarget:nil action:nil];
        return YES;
    }
```

**Update 1**
After some investigations I found out that this approach is not so good. Coz we have problems with long press menu especially with deselecting selected text. And there was still issue for me - do a long tap when menu appear slightly swipe left or right - sometimes WKWebView could start scroll. 
 Next approach is in setting *WKSelectionGranularityCharacter* for *WKWebViewConfiguration* - this is not obvious I must say (Apple why are you doing this?) So then it works fine on iOS8 - there is no double tap, every gesture works as it should be. However for iOS9 we have bad news - http://www.openradar.me/23345435 It was broken. So continue to investigate.

Answer (score 2):

The same idea as there https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939172/2883860 but a little more modern.

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.scrollView.subviews.forEach { subview in
        subview.gestureRecognizers?.forEach { recognizer in
            if let tapRecognizer = recognizer as? UITapGestureRecognizer,
                tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired == 2 && tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired == 1 {
                subview.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **refactored** version, written in Swift 4.2 Just pass your WKWebView as a parameter and call the function somewhere like viewDidLoad.

```
private func deleteDoubleTap(web: WKWebView) {
    for subview in web.scrollView.subviews {            
        let recognizers = subview.gestureRecognizers?.filter{$0 is UITapGestureRecognizer}
        recognizers?.forEach{recognizer in
            let tapRecognizer = recognizer as! UITapGestureRecognizer
            if tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired == 2 && tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired == 1 {
                subview.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.subviews.forEach { subview in
        subview.gestureRecognizers?.forEach { recognizer in
            if let tapRecognizer = recognizer as? UITapGestureRecognizer,
               tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired == 2 {
                subview.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you are under control of the content that you display in that `WKWebView`, you should set the right viewport for it. That will most likely disable this behaviour.

How about:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width; user-scalable=false" />
```

Comment: Yes, I tried with this viewport. But still this scrolling problem :s